How to manipulate parameters of a transistor in PSpice?
.SUBCKT csd17484f4  1   2   3
* PARAMETER (local) DEFINITIONS SECTION
.PARAM  pWidth  12.17604u
.PARAM  pLen    1u
.PARAM  perim   {2.1*pWidth}
.PARAM  ptrc1   3.00e-3     ; temp co of ext Rd / Rs
.PARAM  ptrc2   1.40e-6
****** MODEL SUBCIRCUIT BEGINS HERE     ******************************
M1    10 11 12 12  NMOS W={pWidth} L={pLen} PS={perim} PD={perim}
M2  12 11 12 10  PMOSd W={pWidth} L=0.17u  PS={perim} PD={perim}
DBD    3  1  DBD {1/14}
CBD0     3  1    10e-12
RBD0     3  1    9e9
CGS0     2  3    6e-12
DDG 10 14    DD
DGD 11 14    DD
RGG1     2 21    5.0
RGG2    21 11    20
cgg2    21 11    1e-8
RSB 12  9    RTEMP 57e-3
RSS  9  3  RTEMP 1.0e-3
RDD  1 10  36e-3
DESD1    3  2    DDZ
******************************************************************* 
.MODEL  NMOS   NMOS (    LEVEL  = 7             Version= 3.2  
+ TNOM   = 27            LINT   = 0.050e-6      CAPMOD = 2
+ TOX    = 1.75e-8       NCH    = 1.845e17      NSUB   = 1.0e16
+ AGS    = 0.0           PVAG   = 0.0           U0     = 600
+ A0     = 1.0           A1     = 0.0           A2     = 1.0
+ UA     = 2.0e-9        UB     = 5.87e-19      VBM    = -10
+ UA1    = 2.00e-9       UB1    = -5.0e-19      UTE    = -1.50
+ KT1    = -0.57         KT2    = 0.022         KT1L   = 1.0e-15
+ DVT0   = 2.2           DVT1   = 0.53        DVT2   = -0.033
+ ETA0   = 0.080         ETAB   = -0.07         XJ     = 4e-7
+ PDIBLC1= 0.40          PDIBLC2= 0.0086        NLX    = 1.75e-7
+ PSCBE1 = 4.24e8        PSCBE2 = 1e-6          PCLM   = 1.75
+ VOFF   = -0.19         NFACTOR= 1.20          JS     = 0
+ DROUT  = 1.3           DSUB   = 1.3           DELTA  = 0.02
+ CJ     = 1e-18         CJSW   = 1e-18         CF     = 0
+ CGSO   = 162e-12       CGDO   = 0.1e-12       CGBO   = 1e-18  )
*******************************************************************
.MODEL  PMOSd   PMOS (   LEVEL  = 7           CAPMOD = 0
+ TNOM   = 27            VTO    = -1.0      NCH  = 5e15
+ TOX    = 1.75e-8       K1   = 0.65        K2   =-0.01
+ JS       = 0
+ CJ     = 1e-18         CJSW   = 1e-18     NOFF     = 2.0
+ CGSO   = 1e-18         CGDO   = 1e-18         CGBO   = 1e-18  )
*******************************************************************
.MODEL DBD D (CJO=1.40e-9 VJ=0.87 M=0.35 TNOM=27 FC=0.5 TT=1e-09 
+ XTI=-3.0 BV=32.98 TBV1=7.3e-4 IS=4.6e-10 N=1.125
+ RS=6.44e-3 TRS1=2.0e-3 TRS2=-9.0e-6 ISR=1e-10)
.param abc 1.1e-11
.MODEL DD  D (CJO={abc } VJ=0.40 M=1.50 IS=1e-15 RS=1 TNOM=27)
.MODEL DDx D (CJO={abc /10} VJ=0.6 M=0.95 IS=1e-15 RS=10 TNOM=27)
.MODEL DDZ D (CJO=45e-12 VJ=0.6 M=0.4 IS=4.5e-16 RS=0.2 TNOM=27 
+ TBV1=1.26e-3 bv=15.0 IBVL=5e-9 IBV=1e-7)
*******************************************************************
.MODEL RTEMP RES (TC1={ptrc1} TC2={ptrc2})
*******************************************************************
.ENDS csd17484f4    
*******************************************************************

As you can see above, I'm working on a MOS transistor model, downloaded from Texas Instruments, in Pspice. The problem is that I want to define some new parameters in this model, including: W,L, unCox=200uA/V^2, Vth=0.6v, gamma=0.25 (v^1/2), phif=0.3v, Lambda=0.05 V^-1, rb=100Ohm, VA=20v, and for my bipolar: Is=10^-16 A, Betaf=100. but I don't know how exactly to define them. I mean I don't know the requiring syntax and symbols for them in such models. If someone have any experience with this, I would be very happy, if he can walk me through this.
thanks in advance.

You can check these answers. https://www.edaboard.com/threads/how-to-change-transistor-parameters-in-pspice.199041/

Check the PSpice manual on page 84, to start. And on page 106 where it discusses the X card.
A .SUBCKT really is just a subcircuit. One nice feature over and above nested schematics is that you can specify parameter values and call these like you might a subroutine.
The way this is handled is that the .SUBCKT statement includes an added params: syntax where you can specify parameter names and their default values. And the X card -- the line that calls the .SUBCKT subroutine -- can likewise include an added params: syntax where you can specify matching parameter names and override their default values during the call.
So let's take a very simple case -- a resistor SUBCKT that I'll use below. Let's look:
.SUBCKT MyR pin1 pin2 params: RVAL={1k}
Rmy99 pin1 pin2 {RVAL}
.ENDS      $ Used to be FINIS but now is ENDS
V1 Vcc 0 10
X1 MidPt 0 MyR params: RVAL={500}
X2 Vcc MidPt MyR params: RVAL={750}
X3 Vcc 0 MyR
.OP

Here, I have a \$10\:\text{V}\$ power supply that is connected across two subcircuits that are in series. Both subcircuits are just resistors. So this is, in effect, a voltage source connected to two, in series, resistors. I also added one subcircuit directly across the voltage supply, \$X_3\$. This is so you can see how the default value also works, too.
That's all it is.
Here's the operating point result:
       --- Operating Point ---

V(vcc):  10  voltage
V(midpt):    4   voltage
I(V1):   -0.018  device_current
Ix(1:PIN1):  0.008   subckt_current
Ix(1:PIN2):  -0.008  subckt_current
Ix(2:PIN1):  0.008   subckt_current
Ix(2:PIN2):  -0.008  subckt_current
Ix(3:PIN1):  0.01    subckt_current
Ix(3:PIN2):  -0.01   subckt_current

And, of course, \$\frac{10\:\text{V}}{500\:\Omega\,+\,750\:\Omega}=8 \:\text{mA}\$. And with the way it is arranged (\$X_1\$ tied to ground), \$V_{\text{MidPt}}\$ should work out to be \$10\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}=10\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{500\:\Omega}{500\:\Omega\,+\,750\:\Omega}=4\:\text{V}\$. The current for \$X_3\$ is also the obvious \$10\:\text{mA}\$.
(If you have a long list then you will need multiple lines. But you already know how to do that with + at the beginning of each line.)
Let's say you wanted to modify the subcircuit now, so that it uses twice the passed-in (or default) values. Then:
.SUBCKT MyR pin1 pin2 params: RVAL={1k}
.PARAM AVAL={2*RVAL}
Rmy99 pin1 pin2 {AVAL}
.ENDS
V1 Vcc 0 10
X1 MidPt 0 MyR params: RVAL={500}
X2 Vcc MidPt MyR params: RVAL={750}
X3 Vcc 0 MyR
.OP

I added one .PARAM line and modified the resistor value so that it used AVAL instead of RVAL. The above would simulate so that the divider voltage didn't change but where all the currents would now be half as much as before.
Honestly, it is no more complicated than that.

ok thanks, but do you know how can I define those parameters that I told above? And where can I learn the syntax of this model? I mean should I use a specific syntax for the symbols like betaf, phif?

@Nima_Ebr Page 84 in the PSpice manual. Just be aware of variations in Spice programs. It could be RVAL=1k or RVAL='1k' or RVAL={1k} or some accept all of the above. Did you try to look in the PSpice manual, at all? I'm curious. And are you sincerely in need of hand-holding though your process? I believe you are more than capable of doing this now. But if you need more specific help, then tell me just ONE of the parameters you want adapted that you find confusing to achieve and I will try. Not all of it, though, please.
